# What is the simplest regular expression for excluding a repetition pattern?

Tags: regex, automata, finite-automata, nfa, automata-theory

I've tried writing regular expression for the set of strings that *does not* contain `000` where the alphabet is `{0,1}`. I'm looking for the solution with the least amount of operators.

I've tried:

```
(!+0+00)(1(!+0+00))*
```

[Where](http://www.jflap.org/tutorial/regular/index.html):

- * is the Kleene star
- + is the union operator
- ! is used to represent the empty string.

I'm not sure if it's correct or not either.

I don't know if there are other operators exist like number of occurance etc.

Comment: Perhaps like this if empty stings should not be matched `^(1*0{1,2}(1+0{0,2})*|1+)$` https://regex101.com/r/LNsgnH/1 or a positive lookahead if supported `^(?![01]*000)[01]+$` https://regex101.com/r/yonYZl/1

Comment: Or if empty strings are allowed `^(0{0,2}1+)*0{0,2}$` https://regex101.com/r/NHaDTH/1

Comment: `(!+0+00)((1+10+100)*)`

Comment: @Thefourthbird As far as I know the ones that I mentioned are the only allowed operators.

Comment: When you say simplest, do you mean minimum total operations? What are you counting as operations? Formally, I'd think that Kleene closure (`*`), disjunction (`+`) and concatenation (juxtaposition) are countable operations and jhnc's answer is very close to optimal (however, under these rules, factoring out the 1 and one of the 0s could lower the total number of operations; something like `(!+0(!+0))(1(!+0(!+0)))*`

Comment: @Patrick87 This was an assignment but I think all `*`, `+` and concatenation count as operator.

Comment: @jhnc I think you should put this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple:

```
(!|0|00)(11*(!|0|00))*
```

Because any number of 1's is allowed and between these 1's we can have at most two 0's.
At least if I understood correctly that it was a language in which no element contains substring 000.

Comment: I think you can construct `000` with the pattern above by 3 times (0 times 1 and 1 times 0). Besides this doesn't allow for 1s without 0s.

Comment: Yes, that's true. I meant to do 11*. I corrected the answer.